# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP: manager cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, jdbc, ide

estoy utlizando xamp para crear mi base de datos.
tengo netbeans 13 con jdk 18 y me descargue el conector jdbc 8
me sale el siguiente error:

> excepción
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP:
>
> Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [5] en el archivo jsp: [/consulta.jsp]
> manager cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
2: 
3: <%
4: Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
5: Connection MiConexionCN = Driver.manager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mibase1","root","");
6: Statement declararObjetoBdST = MiConexionCN.createStatement();
7: ResultSet datosObtenidosRS = declararObjetoBdST.executeQuery ("select *  from mitabla");
```

Este es mi codigo en JSP:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection MiConexionCN = Driver.manager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mibase1","root","");
Statement declararObjetoBdST = MiConexionCN.createStatement();
ResultSet datosObtenidosRS = declararObjetoBdST.executeQuery ("select *  from mitabla");

while (datosObtenidosRS.next()){
out.println(datosObtenidosRS.getString("codigo"));
out.println(datosObtenidosRS.getString("nombres"));
out.println(datosObtenidosRS.getString("apellidos"));
out.println("<br>");
 
}
    
datosObtenidosRS.close();
declararObjetoBdST.close();
MiConexionCN.close();

%>
```

---

es cierto; sin embargo ahora me sale otro error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Ha sucedido una excepción al procesar la página JSP [/index.jsp] en línea [11]

8: <%@include file="consulta.jsp" %>
9: <!DOCTYPE html>
10: <html>
11:     <head>
12:         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
13:         <title>JSP Page</title>
14:     </head>
```

este es mi codigo index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@include file="consulta.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿¿`Driver.manager`?? Es `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`.